# Cramer-Wold consequence

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

> **Corollary 6.5** (one-dimensional projections, Cramér & Wold) For any random vectors $\xi, \xi_1 , \xi_2 , . . . \in \mathbb{R}^d$ or
> $\mathbb{R}^d_+$ , we have
>
> (i) $\xi_n \overset{d}{\to} \xi$ in $\mathbb{R}^d \iff t \xi_n \overset{d}{\to} t \xi, t \in
>  \mathbb{R}^d$ ,
>
> (ii) $\xi_n \overset{d}{\to} \xi$ in $\mathbb{R}^d_+ \iff u \xi_n \overset{d}{\to} u \xi, u ∈
>  \mathbb{R}^d_+ $.
>
> In particular, the distribution of a random vector $\xi$ in
> $\mathbb{R}^d$ or $\mathbb{R}^d_+$ is uniquely determined by those of
> all linear combinations $t\xi$ with $t\in \mathbb{R}^d$ or
> $\mathbb{R}^d_+$ , respectively.

I don't understand the part "In particular...". It seems to say that as a consequence of the corrolary, if $X:=(X_1,\ldots,X_k)$ and $Y:=(Y_1,\ldots,Y_k)$ are random vectors such that any linear combinations are the same, i.e. $c_1X_1+\ldots c_kX_k=c_1Y_1+\ldots c_k Y_k$ then $X\overset{d}{=}Y$ which is not so clear to me from the corrollary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second implication can be seen as a consequence of the first one. That is, if $\xi_n=Y$ for all $n$ and $Y\overset{d}{=}X$, then it is clear that $\xi_n\xrightarrow{d}X$ which is equivalent to $t^{\top}\xi_n\to t^{\top}X$ or $t^{\top}Y=t^{\top}X$ for any $t\in\mathbb{R}^d$.

Comment: I am going to rephrase what you said to be sure I understand. If $t^TY=t^TX$ for every $t$, considering the sequence $(\xi_n)_{\ge1}=(Y,Y,Y,...)$ we have $t^T\xi_n=t^TY\overset{d}{\to} t^TY=t^TX$. Since $t$ is arbitrary, by the Corrollary, we have $\xi_n\overset{d}{\to}X$. However by definition of the sequence $\xi_n\overset{d}{\to}Y$ so we conclude $X\overset{d}{=}Y$